# Dart how do I find the index of true value in the list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have list `List<bool> _selections = [false, true, false];` and this list may change only one can be true

How do I know which index is true ?

Comment: only one can be true, I just want to find the true one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [indexWhere](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/indexWhere.html)

```
_selections.indexWhere((value) => value)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `indexWhere()` method.

```
_selections.indexWhere((ele) => ele);
```

[See more](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/indexWhere.html)

Answer (score 2):

while the above answer are correct and simpler you can also use a good old foreach loop like this:

```
for (var elements in _selections) {
    if (elements == true) {
      print(elements);
    }
  }
```